# On checkbox click in datagridview (devexpress) get row data in .net maui

Tags: c#, devexpress, maui

Hello I am creating an datagridview in .net maui.
The datagrid contains tasks, as last column their is an checkbox you can click on.
You say the task is done.
[image: Picture of datagrid]

Their is an desktop application and an mobile application. So when their is an click on the checkbox in the column "Afgewerkt", I want to change the state in the database. But to know that I need to know te row. I have an ObservableCollection where al the tasks are. Every task have a id. I want to know the ID.

I have now this function:

```
private async void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedMelding = ((VisualElement)sender).BindingContext as Melding;
    var state = (bool)e.Value;
    if (state)
    {
        await _viewmodel.ChangeAfgewerkt(selectedMelding.Id, state);
    }
}
```

XAML CODE:

```
<dxg:DataGridView x:Name="dgMeldingen" ItemsSource="{Binding Meldingen}" Margin="16" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding GetMeldingenCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" DoubleTap="DataGridView_DoubleTap">
        <dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderAppearance>
            <dxg:ColumnHeaderAppearance BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource Primaryxxxlight}" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalLineThickness="2"/>
        </dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderAppearance>
        
        <dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
            <!--<dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Naam" HorizontalHeaderAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <dxg:TextColumn.BindingContext>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="BurgerInformation.Name" />
                        <Binding Path="BurgerInformation.FirstName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </dxg:TextColumn.BindingContext>
            </dxg:TextColumn>-->
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="BurgerInformation.Name" HorizontalHeaderAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <dxg:TextColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="Naam" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TextColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
            </dxg:TextColumn>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="BurgerInformation.FirstName" HorizontalHeaderAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <dxg:TextColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="Voornaam" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TextColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
            </dxg:TextColumn>
            <dxg:TextColumn FieldName="Created"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <dxg:TextColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="Datum" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TextColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
            </dxg:TextColumn>
            <dxg:CheckBoxColumn FieldName="Heterdaad" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                <dxg:CheckBoxColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="Niet HD &lt;-> HD" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:CheckBoxColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
            </dxg:CheckBoxColumn>
            <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="Afgewerkt" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" >
                <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Melding">
                        <CheckBox HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Afgewerkt}" CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged" IsEnabled="{Binding Afgewerkt}">

                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                <dxg:TemplateColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="Afgewerkt" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TemplateColumn.HeaderContentTemplate>
            </dxg:TemplateColumn>
        </dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
    </dxg:DataGridView>
```

Someone that can give the right direction?

Thanks In Advance!!!!

***UPDATE:***

I found an workaround so I can use command and commandparameters but I have then another problem.

```
<dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="Afgewerkt" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" >
                <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Melding">
                        <CheckBox HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Afgewerkt}">
                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                    EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference Afgewerkt}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                    Command="{Binding ChangeAfgewerktCommand}" />
                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
```

Thecommand is not working because the datatype of my checkbox is Melding.

Comment: Well, usually you bind boolean values to checkboxes. Then, observe the changes. When you click button, the value changes. When the value changes, you update the database. Alternative - you can bind to commands. The parameter can be your object. Accessing your VisualElements is not very good design choice.

Comment: @H.A.H. it is not possible to use a Command or Commandproperties on Checkboxes in .NET MAUI

Comment: Found a workaround to use commands and commandparameter but need an other workaround to use the command

Comment: This "workaround" that you "found" is exactly the "bind to commands" solution that I told you to do. Try now to "find workaround" by binding to the IsChecked property, and implementing partial OnPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification about my comment to command binding:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:SomeModel">
    <SomeVisualElement>
       <SomeVisualElement.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding SomeProperty}"
                                  Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:SomeViewModel}}, Path=DoSomethingCommand}"/>
       </SomeVisualElement.GestureRecognizers>
    </SomeVisualElement>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here we have DataTemplate. We specify the DataType of that DataTemplate. The template has DataType, there is no such thing as "Datatype of my checkbox". The visual element, no matter what kind, does not have a data type.

Next, we bind to some command. Maybe a button will have command. Maybe a gesture recognizer. Maybe we use Behavior of some sort. It really does not matter. What matters here is, that we find our ViewModel. Since we are in the context of the Item (SomeModel type), we need to search for it. This is why we use RelativeSource binding.

As for the CommandParameter, we can address the Properties directly. (Since we specified the DataType). If the class SomeModel, has property SomeProperty, we can bind to it directly.

Here is good place to say, that we can also do this {Binding .} , very useful to give us the whole SomeModel item.

When the Visual Element gets tapped on, the DoSomethingCommand will be called, and the parameter we bound will be passed. We can then delete/insert/edit it in the database. Or whatever...

Alternative:
We bind directly to the property we want:
For example:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:SomeModel">
    <SomeVisualElement SomeBindableProperty="{Binding SomeProperty}">
         ...
```

When the BindableProperty gets modified (lets say, this was IsChecked, and the user clicked), our property in our model will get changed.

And then when the setter triggers, we will be inserting/deleting/updating it in the DB.